# How can I remove span12 from the div before the article

Tags: overrides, template-override

In the past when I did an article override I used to get:

`default.php`
`default_item.php`
`default_links.php`
`default_child.php`

all of which were placed in `templates/MYTEMPLATE/html/com_content/article/`

Now when I do an override I only get `default.php` and `default_links.php`.  The old `default.php` used to contain the part which has `span12` in it.  Here's the code in question which can be found on any single article page.

```
<div class="platform-content row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <!-- the start of my single article override -->
    <div class="local-area">
```

When I look in `components/com_content/views/article/tmpl` I still don't see the oldfiles to copy.

1. What happened to them and why?
2. How do old overrides still work?
3. And most of all, how can I remove span12 from the div prior to the article?  I'm doing a pretty big override and I need to put something just before that.  I know I can do this with JavaScript but I prefer to use an override if possible.

Comment: It will be great if you post some code and file/folder structure in question , Code always tells you true story :)

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this, you want me to share the entire code of a single article view?  I have changed my question to add just the code I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `span12` is probably not created by the override or the content component. Check to see if it appears before all component `div` wrappers. If it is before every component, it is created by the template layout.

To change this you will want to change the template’s index.php file. Some template creators split the layout into several PHP files. If so, you will want to look for a file called component.php or something similar.

However, you will want to be careful removing the `span12` class from the template itself. It could cause problems with other components or the page layout.

Comment: Hmm, ok I'll look there.  This definitely used to be part of the override system.

Comment: This just can't be the template as it's not using Bootstrap.  It is definitely Joomla! core and part of the article page.

Comment: If you run a search through the Joomla 3 core source code, you will NOT find `span12` anywhere that impacts the frontend layout of your articles. It is definitely NOT from the Joomla core. Both `span12` and `row-fluid` are Boostrap 2 classes. If it is not your template, it is a plugin. However, creating a plugin to add the HTML would be a really strange idea. I am 98% sure it is caused by the template. Use a CLI to run a search for `span12` in your Joomla site or download the template and search it on your local computer.

Comment: Joomla! core has Bootstrap 2 built into it.  And unfortunately that is what I'm trying to overcome.  See here for the example https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog.php#L100 my template isn't using Bootstrap it's using Gantry, but there's loads of places to override to fix that.

Comment: I think I'll just use No Numbers rereplacer :)

Comment: You are right. Bootstrap 2 is what the core is based on. However, I see the code you reference is part of the Category view, the override files you said you used to get also look like the Category view / Category Blog layout (just `blog` is `default`). But the files you get now as well as the place you are putting them is the Article view. It is conceivable that if you copied the Category Blog layout and used it in the Article view passing it a single article object it would display that article. However, I imagine you would hit some fatal errors. Your overrides may be mixed up.

Comment: They aren't, I used  the backend to create the overrides so they can't be.

Comment: It is coming from your Gantry template. `libraries/gantry5/classes/Gantry/Framework/Platform.php` line 31. Your template is using `$component_wrapper` somewhere.

Comment: How did you find this?

Comment: I searched Gantry for 'platform-content'. Once I downloaded it, it only took a minute to find. It looks like `Platform.php` uses it on lines 46 and 261 but that is it. The second one looks like it probably the source of the issue.

Comment: I've asked them on Gitter and that should hopefully give me an answer.